# $p|p\sqrt{n}-q|$ is bounded below by a positive number

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n \in \Bbb{N}^+$ be a non-square number, show that $\forall p,q \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $p>0$,

$p|p\sqrt{n}-q| > A$ for some $A>0$.

I found a proof of this proposition that goes as follows:

$(p\sqrt{n}-q)(p\sqrt{n}+q) = p^2 n - q^2$ is a non-zero integer, therefore

$|p\sqrt{n}-q| \times |p\sqrt{n}+q| \ge 1$. Let $A = min(\sqrt{n},\frac{1}{4\sqrt{n}})$.

If $|p\sqrt{n}-q| < p\sqrt{n}$ then

$|p\sqrt{n}+q| = |-2p\sqrt{n} + (p\sqrt{n}-q)| \le |2p\sqrt{n}| + |p\sqrt{n}-q| < 3p\sqrt{n}$, therefore

$|p\sqrt{n}-q| \ge \frac{1}{|p\sqrt{n}+q|} > \frac{1}{3p\sqrt{n}} > \frac{A}{p}$.

If $|p\sqrt{n}-q| \ge p\sqrt{n}$ then

$|p\sqrt{n}-q| \ge p\sqrt{n} \ge Ap > \frac{A}{p}$.

I understand this proof, I just find it very unintuitive. How are we supposed to know that we should consider the cases $|p\sqrt{n}-q| < p\sqrt{n}$ and $|p\sqrt{n}-q| \ge p\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: You probably want to add that $n$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @MartinR Whoops! Thank you.